Set Last Value in __m128 vector register
So I have a set of data with mixed values for packing purposes that goes like this:
{(Point_x, Point_y, Point_z, Scalar),
 (Point_x, Point_y, Point_z, Scalar),
 (Point_x, Point_y, Point_z, Scalar),
...}

Where each Point_x, Point_y, Point_z, and Scalar are 32 bit floats.
Because of that I can load each point aligned, but i need to move the point x,y,z into its own register for my operation and then set the last value to a 1.f in the __m128 register (where scalar would be). What instruction is used to set the last value to a 1.f in the register and leave the other values untouched?
currently I am doing:
    __m128 rPointMixed = _mm_load_ps( (float*)pPoint );
    __m128 rOne =_mm_set1_ps(1.f);
    __m128 rPoint = _mm_blend_ps(rPointMixed,rOne,0x8);

but might not be the most efficent solution, i am fine with sse4/avx/avx2 instruction though if it there is a really efficent way with them
struct Vec4f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float scalar;
};

Vec4f vData[10000];

//in reality this loop is unrolled to do 8 at a time, but rolled up for simplicity sake
for( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    __m128 rPointData = _mm_load_ps( (float*)vData[i] );
    //math there where it permutes the scalar and does math with it

   //3 just cause it is the last value?
   __m128 rPoint = [unknownIntrinsic](rPointData ,1.f, 3); //?
  
  //point math here

}

Thanks for the help in advance

The index of the last element is 3, not 4.  But as LHLaurini says, blendps is more efficient than insertps or any other shuffle, and the set1 is free since it's a constant.  If you had a runtime-variable scalar to insert, insertps would be worth considering.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/insertps  (_mm_insert_ps takes a vector source, so you'd be relying on the optimizer to optimize away a _mm_set or broadcast.)

If you did _mm_blend_ps just after _mm_load_ps, could be useful to reverse the blend: _mm_blend_ps(rOne,rPointMixed,0x7). With AVX enabled, the compiler could save rOne to a register preserve during the loop, and compile_mm_blend_ps and _mm_load_ps into one instruction with memory operand. But with computed operand it is not helpful.

Unless there's an instruction with a better throughput than blendps (0.33 CPI on Intel), what you're doing is already ideal.
Note that you don't actually need to call _mm_set1_ps(1.f) for every iteration of the loop (so your "unknown intrinsic" is actually just _mm_blend_ps), as rOne is constant. With optimizations enabled, however, most compilers will be smart enough to do that just once before the loop.
